# Any tips for installing CVS Server and Tortoise Client on Windows 7?

Tags: version-control, windows-7, cvs, tortoisecvs

I'm installing CVS and the Tortoise client on Win 7.  Getting a warning "CVSNT Locking Service... failed to start. Verify you have sufficient  privileges to start services"

I'm running as Admin with UAC off.

Comment: Any particular reason you are going for CVS rather than Subversion?

Comment: The repository is already in CVS and it's what I'm familiar with.  (I know Subversion is superior but I found it difficult to use when I tried it.)

Comment: You know that there is a Tortoise for SVN too? I found it to be very similar to the CVS Tortoise.